# How do I write a script that configures an applications settings for me?

Tags: python, shell, vlc

I need help on how to write a script that configures an applications (VLC) settings to my needs without having to do it manually myself. The reason for this is because I will eventually need to start this application on boot with the correct settings already configured.

Steps I need done in the script.

1)  I need to open the application.

2)  Open the “Open Network Stream…” tab (Can be done with Ctrl+N).

3)  Type a string of characters “String of characters”

4)  Push “Enter” twice on the keyboard.

I’ve checked various websites across the internet and could not find any information regarding this. I am sure it’s possible but I am new to writing scripts and not too experienced. Are commands like the steps above possible to be completed in a script?

Note: Using Linux based OS (Raspbian).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do whichever changes you want manually once on an arbitrary system, then make a copy of the application's configuration files (in this case `~/.config/vlc`)

When you want to replicate the settings on a different machine, simply copy the settings to the same location.